# How to unbind all the socket.io events from my backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js, socket.io, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a page which include two backbone views (views related to two template). I am changing content of one views based on clicking event on different items on another view. For this, Every time I click on any items in one view I just create a instance of another view which include some socket.io events. At the first time It's work well but everytime I click on item on first view it just create the instance of 2nd one so that all the socket.io events is binding. Except first click every time I click on items on first view and call an socket.io events, it fired more than one time based on how many click I have done to different items.

I know that every time I click an items it create an instance of a view with socket.io  event bind. But I can not get the way to unbind the previous socket.io events.

I have tried to use this reference:
[Backbone.js View removing and unbinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080763/backbone-js-view-removing-and-unbinding)
But it is not working in my case. May be I did not use it in proper way.

Can anyone please give me a solution or way to unbind all the socket.io events binded before?

Here is my Clicking event from where I am creating a new instance of another view where all the socket.io events binds.

```
 LoadQueueDetails: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var queues = new Queues();

    queues.fetch({
        data: $.param({ Code: this.model.get("QueueCode") }),
        success: function () {
            $("#grid21").html(new SearchResultListView({ collection: queues }).el);
        },
        error: function (queues) {
            alert('error found in fetch queue details');
        }
    });
   }
```

And here is my actual view where I bind all the socket.io events.

```
window.SearchResultListView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function () {
    this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);
    this.render();
},

render: function () {
    var Queues = this.collection;
    var len = Queues.length;

    $(this.el).html(this.template());

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        $('.QueueListItem', this.el).append(new SearchResultListItemView({ model: Queues.models[i]}).render().el);
    }
    return this;
 }
});


window.SearchResultListItemView = MainView.extend({
tagName: "tr",

initialize: function () {

    this.__initialize();

    var user;
    if ($.super_cookie().check("user_cookie")) {
        this.user = $.super_cookie().read_JSON("user_cookie");
    }     

    this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    this.model.on("destroy", this.close, this);
    socket.emit('adduser', this.user.UserName, this.model.get("Code"));
},

events: {
    "click a": "JoinQueue"
},

onClose: function(){
    this.model.unbind("change", this.render);
},
close: function () {
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
    this.model.unbind("change", this.render);
},
socket_events: {
    "updatechat": "updatechat",
    "changeroom": "changedroom"
},
changedroom: function (username, data) {
    alert(data);
    socket.emit('switchRoom', data);
},

updatechat: function (username, data) {
    alert(username);
    alert(data);
},

JoinQueue: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($.super_cookie().check("user_cookie")) {
        user = $.super_cookie().read_JSON("user_cookie");
    }

    socket.emit('sendchat', "new user");
},

render: function () {
    var data = this.model.toJSON();
    _.extend(data, this.attributes);
    $(this.el).html(this.template(data));
    return this;
}
});


window.Queue = Backbone.Model.extend({

urlRoot: "/queue",
initialize: function () {
},

defaults: {
    _id:null,
    Code: null,
    ServiceEntityId: null,
    ServiceEntityName:null,
    Name: null,
    NoOfWaiting: null,
    ExpectedTimeOfService: null,
    Status: null,
    SmsCode: null
}

});

window.Queues = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Queue,
url: "/queue",

initialize: function () {
}
});

Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
this.remove();
this.unbind();
if (this.onClose) {
    this.onClose();
}
}
```

And this is my main view to bind socket.io event in searchResultItemview.

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function () {
    this.__initialize();
},

__initialize: function () {
    if (this.socket_events && _.size(this.socket_events) > 0) {
        this.delegateSocketEvents(this.socket_events);
    }
},

delegateSocketEvents: function (events) {

    for (var key in events) {
        var method = events[key];
        if (!_.isFunction(method)) {
            method = this[events[key]];
        }

        if (!method) {
            throw new Error('Method "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');
        }

        method = _.bind(method, this);
        socket.on(key, method);
    };
}
});
```

For extra information:

```
1. I am opening socket connection globally. Like this :
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

I am waiting for any kind of advice or solution to get out of this problem. Please feel free to ask any kind of inquiries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to do `socket.removeListener` for every `socket.on` when you close your View.

You can update your MainView and add a `close` method.

This is how it looks in my code (CoffeeScript)

```
close: ->
    self = @
    _.each @socket_events, (method, key) ->
        method = self[self.socket_events[key]]
        socket.removeListener key, method
```