# Using backbonejs view, what is the best way to attach an "onload" event to an image tag?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I want to attach an "onload" event for an image in a backbonejs view. I am currently including it in the "events" as "load img":"function", but it is not getting fired off.

Any suggestions for doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Backbone's event handling is based on [`delegate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7802255/479863) and `delegate` can only be used with events that bubble. The problem is that load events do not bubble; from the [HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-img-element.html#img-load):

> **If the download was successful**
>   Set the `img` element to the completely available state, update the presentation of the image appropriately, and fire a simple event named `load` at the `img` element.

And a [*simple event*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) does not bubble:

> **Firing a simple event named *e*** means that an event with the name *e*, which does not bubble (except where otherwise stated) [...]

So you'll have to hook up a handler by hand with something like this:

```
render: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.append(some_html_with_img_elements);
    this.$el.find('img').on('load', function() { self.img_loaded() });
    return this;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/c7wH2/

Comment: Perfect! That helped. Yes, I noticed the event bubbling problem while using "on" method of jquery. I was wondering, if backbonejs implemented a different logic. But, I did not know about the "simple events" yet. Thanks for the answer