# Backbone.js view img onload

Tags: events, backbone.js, image, onload

I'm struggling with backbone.js. I'm pretty new to js and used to as3 what is more object orientated

I try to make an simple image gallery with backbone. I load 100 images and i want them to fade in if they are loaded.

I have this in my AppView. For every image url I get i create one PhotoView

```
var view = new PhotoView({model: photo, list:this.imageList});
this.imageList.append(view.render().el);
```

In the Photoview I use this code to attach the onload() on the img tag (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829580/using-backbonejs-view-what-is-the-best-way-to-attach-an-onload-event-to-an-im)):

```
render: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.append(some_html_with_img_elements);
    this.$el.find('img').on('load', function() { self.img_loaded() });
    return this;
}
```

The problem is that in the img_loaded() i get the same view over and over (the last view). Anyone know how to keep reference to the right view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `this` as an argument to `img_loaded`, so that you'll get a reference to the image that just loaded, and manipulate it however you want.

Since you didn't post the code for the `img_loaded` function I'm not sure if you're trying to fade them in one at a time as each is loaded (a simple job once you pass in the image reference), or wait until they're all loaded and fade them all in at once (would need some extra code for that).

Comment: You are right. I also missed a little thing in the progress of copying the code. I missed the 'var' before 'var self = this'

Answer (score 0):

You can pass referance of view to call back function like this.

```
var me = this;
me.$el.find("img").on("load", { me: me }, function (event) { event.data.me.img_loaded(); });
```