# Working with an image error event in a Backbone view

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, backbone-events

Within an Underscore template used by a Backbone view I have an image. I'm trying to attach to the error event and change the image source if the original image is not found.

Based on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829580/using-backbonejs-view-what-is-the-best-way-to-attach-an-onload-event-to-an-im), I took the following approach:

```
render: function() { 
    var self = this;

    this.$el.html( this.template( { person: this.model.toJSON() } ) ); 

    this.$el.find('img.employee-image').on('error', function(evt) { this.src = "assets/images/_noimage.gif"; });

    return this;
}
```

This works perfectly well, but if I try to move the changing of the src to a separate method in the view, the method will be called but the image will not change.

```
render: function() { 
    var self = this;

    this.$el.html( this.template( { person: this.model.toJSON() } ) ); 

    this.$el.find('img.employee-image').on('error', function(evt) { self.handleMissingImage(evt); });

    return this;
},

handleMissingImage: function(evt) {
    // This by itself did not work.
    // this.src = "assets/images/_noimage.gif";

    var i = $(evt.currentTarget);
    i.src = "assets/images/_noimage.gif";
    console.log(i.src);
}
```

Logging the src out shows "assets/images/_noimage.gif" but the image will not appear. I know it exists because the first approach outlined above works fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is right here:

```
i.src = "assets/images/_noimage.gif";
```

In your `handleMissingImage` function you say:

```
i = $(evt.currentTarget);
```

so `i` is a jQuery object, not a raw DOM element. That means that you want to say `i.attr('src', ...)` to change the `src` attribute or don't bother wrapping `evt.currentTarget` at all.

Comment: Man I hate silly mistakes like that. Thanks for the help! I went with: evt.currentTarget.src = "assets/images/_noimage.gif";