# In a Backbone View's delegated event, how to access the source element of the event?

Tags: backbone.js

I am in the process of rewriting jQuery code to Backbone, but am stuck on a seemingly trivial issue:

Inside an event callback on an element that's a child of the main View element, how do I access the specific child element that was clicked (for example)?

```
var Composer = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #postnow":  "postnow"
    },
    postnow: function(){
        // @fixme:
        var btn = $("#postnow");
        // Do something
    }
});

new Composer({el: $('.composer')});
```

In jQuery, I would use `$(this)`, but in Backbone it refers to the View element, not the clicked child.

Is there any way to do that without explicitly specifying the selector again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone View event getting the proper target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077961/backbone-view-event-getting-the-proper-target)

Comment: @muistooshort Not really, but thanks for linking to this interesting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In view callbacks, you have access to the jQuery events and their properties, more specifically to [event.currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)

Try

```
var Composer = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #postnow":  "postnow"
    },
    postnow: function(e){
        var btn = $(e.currentTarget);
    }
});
```

Comment: @fguillen But you provided a Fiddle, that counts :)

Comment: Got it, thanks! Seems a bit convoluted for such a frequent scenario though, I wonder why there isn't a Backbone shortcut for this.

Comment: This still bugs me -- @fguillen nikoshr do any of you have any idea why? Is it not a very frequent scenarion?

Comment: @julien_c Backbone delegates the event handling to jQuery/Zepto and relies on them for the callbacks, Backbone does not wrap your functions and won't intercept the events to present shortcuts or syntactic sugar. Moreover, Jeremy Ashkenas, the author of Backbone, has a very "minimalist" approach to what Backbone should handle for you, if no real benefit can be seen. Thus, no wrapper around your element. And $(e.target) isn't that long :)

Answer (score 0):

A implicit parameter is sent to the *function callback* this parameter is a [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and it contains a lot of information including the DOM Element where the event was targeted:

```
var Composer = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #postnow":  "postnow"
    },
    postnow: function( event ){
        console.log( "postnow()" );
        console.log( "this", this );
        console.log( "event", event ); 
        console.log( "target", event.target ); 
        console.log( "data-value", $(event.target).attr( "data-value" ) ); 
    }
});
```

Check the [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/6frH6/)